# How do I establish a threshold value for an asymptote?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, asymptotics

I am testing a method on data *x*, which gives a binary result, correct/incorrect. As *x* approaches 0, the percentage of tests which yield a correct result tend to 0. As *x* approach infinity, the percentage of tests which yield a correct result tend to 100%.

I would like to establish the value of *x* for which the probability of getting a correct result is, say, 99.99%.

I have tried fitting a curve in R using the nonlinear least-squares estimate as follows:

```
a <- 100
fit<-nls(PercentCorrect ~ a*(1-u*exp(-b*x)), start=list(u=1, b=1/3))
```

Unfortunately, this curve tends to be too "optimistic" - it gives a 99.99% threshold for a value of *x*, when that value or higher has an observable error rate of 99% - 99.9%.

What can I do to establish a threshold value for x? The approach should preferably be accurate, and failing that, pessimistic (i.e. setting the threshold value higher than required, not lower).

Comment: The first paragraph of your question appears to describe a textbook example of logistic regression (in R a `glm` with `family = "binomial"`), although you would have to use recorded success/failure values instead of the percentage. If a GLM doesn't fit well enough, you could try a GAM.